# There are big differences between Rails 3 and 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to learn Ruby on Rails, up to now I've always developed with PHP but now I'd like to try something new and I found this (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) book online which relies on Ruby 3.0 while the last version is 3.2.1

there are big differences between Rails 3 and 3.2, if yes there may be big problems using this book and which are this changes?

EDIT: if you know some other resources please post them

Answer (score 2):

More resources are available for differences between rails 3 and 3.1, because the differences are major. So here you go -

[official announcement](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/8/31/rails-3-1-0-has-been-released)

[railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/265-rails-3-1-overview)

[a slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/dynamicclarity/rails-31-awesomeness-whats-new)

[few](http://startscratching.com/2011/08/31/whats-new-in-rails-3-1-0/) [blog](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails-3-1.html) posts

And then checkout rails 3.2

[announcement](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/20/rails-3-2-0-faster-dev-mode-routing-explain-queries-tagged-logger-store)

[railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2)

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are differences but the main concepts of rails 3.0 and 3.2 are of course similar and therefore a book/course on rails 3.0 would provide you with a lot of things that you could still use in 3.2.

In my experience the major differences are related to "best practices" and internal structures of rails.

Please consider having a look at [railsforzombies.org](http://railsforzombies.org)

It's a little bit outdated as well but really useful in my eyes.